# Displaying TextView Text with resource layout

Tags: c#, android, layout, textview, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and have a question about displaying text in a TextView.

Here is my code:

```
        string stringNameDisplayText = "Test Name";
        string stringOwnerDisplayText = "Test Owner";
        string stringAddressDisplayText = "Test Address";
        string stringPhoneDetailsDisplayText = "0800 832 832";
        string stringWebDetailsDisplayText = "http://www.google.co.nz";
        string stringEmailDetailsDisplayText = "me@me.co.nz";
        string stringComentsDisplayText = "Test comments";

        var labelName = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewName);
        labelName.Text = stringNameDisplayText;

        var labelOwner = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewOwner);
        labelOwner.Text = stringOwnerDisplayText;

        var labelAddress = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewAddress);
        labelOwner.Text = stringAddressDisplayText;
```

Here is my resource layout file code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewName" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"/> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewOwner" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"/> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewAddress" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"/>    

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewPhone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"/>    

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewWeb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"/> 

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewEmail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewComments" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, I cannot display the stringOwnerDisplayText at the same time as the stringAddressDisplayText. If I comment out the labelOwner code, the stringAddressDisplayText is displayed correctly and if I comment out the labelAddress then the stringOwnerDisplayText is displayed correctly. If both are not commented out, only the stringNameDisplayText and stringAddressDisplayText are shown instead of the stringNameDisplayText, stringOwnerDisplayText and stringAddressDisplayText.

Can I please have some help to get this working correctly.

Comment: is there a mistake with your code.? 
 'var labelOwner' you assign it two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that because you assign labelOwner two times ?

try this :

```
var labelOwner = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewOwner);
    labelOwner.Text = stringOwnerDisplayText;

var labelAddress = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewAddress);
labelAddress.Text = stringAddressDisplayText;
```